# Add to url extra parameter based on page value

Tags: php, url

In my PHP site, I have an item page and the url looks like this:

```
Item.php?id=100
```

I want to make it SEO friendly and add the title of the item to the url, but because titles are not unique and ids are unique I just want to add the title with dash, like this:

```
Item.php?id=100-digital-camera-8-megapixel
```

Can it be done with `.htaccess`? Or do I need to change my site's PHP code?

Comment: you have to add that value in to your links

Comment: But I want to make it be accessed by both.

Comment: item.php would get the id and spit it to return the number (if it exists) then use the number

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using htaccess.

You can also use code on php

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $parameter = $_GET['id'];
   $parts = explode('-', $parameter);
   $id = $parts[0];
}
```

Now when you go to your item.php?id=100-camera-8-mp, then the $id will have a value of 100.

If you go for htaccess, it should look like something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^item.php?id=([0-9]+)-(.*)$ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: where does "digital-camera-8-megapixel" come from in this code?

Comment: the htaccess part or php part?

Comment: Digital camera 8 magepixel come fron my item heading

Comment: You should be more specific on that part.